# UILabel with fix max lines iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want a UILabel to restrict for 3 lines. but when only 1 line is required it should resize to 1 line

in the interface builder if I make line = 3. than I can see extra spaces

The solution I need should be in swift 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autolayout.
1. For the label give appropriate constraints on top and bottom. 
2. Set the number of lines to 3.
It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Set line=3 in interface, then in code change label height based on the text

```
   CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(widthOfLabel, FLT_MAX);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```